# Why have an email address associated with iMessage?

Tags: email, messages

Seems to me like this only confuses, since conversations are separated by address/phone number. Are their any advantages, or is it safe to remove all email address from my iMessage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, the main reason to iMessage to emails, was so that users could receive them on their Mac, iPad, or iPod Touch. However, iOS 6 and Mountain Lion allow the user to sync Messages across all their devices. This works great as long as the recipient has a iPhone, and have updated their software to the latest version. If they just have an iPad, for example, you would want to text their email address, as they wouldn't have a phone number to associate with. Also, some people don't update their devices as soon as one comes available, and as a result, some may still be using iOS 5 which wouldn't support that functionality.

Beyond those reasons, there should be no reason, why not to text someone's phone number. In fact, that is basically all I do.